# How do meta discussions lead to decisions?

Tags: discussion

Meta questions tagged with [discussion](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/discussion), is an interesting tool to have .... discussions!

**But**, similar to real world discussions, they should lead to some conclusion/decision. Be it by going for the answer with the highest number of voting balance, or via whatever other criteria you may want to pick.

However, how can "I" (say in X months from now), find out what the ultimate decision was (or if there is one already or not) about any meta question tagged as discussion?

Somehow related: I doubt that just using "the accepted answer" is a valid answer to my question ... Think about what kind of situations that could lead to for anything "you" would want to be decided about: (1) ask a question (2) wait for any answer that "you" like best and mark that as accepted (3) if no answer fits what you like, just post your own answer and mark that as accepted ... That can't be right, right?

BTW, I'd also love to see 1 such existing meta question, where I can see what the decision was.

Comment: Related: [How is consensus determined on Meta sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/177550/how-is-consensus-determined-on-meta-sites)

Comment: @Aurora0001 indeed related, merci (+ also for the typo corrections). Would you agree that an answer like so is what could be the solution: (1) Post 1 answer with 1 possible answer/solution to the topic of the discussion and (2) have anybody vote up/down to express agree/disagree and (3) consider the voting balance of each answer as an indication of what the concensus (instead of the decision) is and (4)be aware that it is not always the consensus that gets implemented by those who have the authority about the ultimate decision PS: not sure if I should rework this comment to my own answer.

Comment: If the position in the question is agreed, no answer could be a valid option too, and the post vote support it. This avoid self answering yourself on meta

Comment: @Tensibai good point, have to remember that also ... So something like "Correct me if I'm wrong (by posting an alternative solution via your own answer), but I think so and so".

Answer (score 1):

Nice question!

So, in my experience with StackExchange, this is how I think the discussion questions trigger a change:

1. Question is asked
2. If it's straight-forward, then a direct answer can sometimes suffice.
3. If not, then the community needs to decide on the answer. So, this triggers a series of events, which means a lot of comments underneath the answers(which are mostly opinions from experienced folks, and also the suggestions from new folks).
4. Chat is a crucial part of this. There **will** be a chat discussion in the chatroom regarding the question, if it is something which is crucial for the future of the site.
5. And, after a detailed discussion of the community, a consensus is reached, and the better answers keep coming up, which will be voted, and finally the OP accepts the answer which he/she thinks is backed by the better part of the community.

So, it's not like, once you ask a question, a couple of folks answer it and you accept one of them. They're an entire process in themselves. :)

^ Also, one reason why [discussion](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/discussion) posts don't get accepted so early.

PS: [An example of such post](https://ai.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1099/101), from my experience.